# How to prevent getServerSideProps from running again when pushing query param?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-router

I'm asking because I don't know exactly what to do. When my page is loaded, I have a table yield that I got from the API with `getServerSideProps`. Like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (
  context
) => {
  const { query } = context
  const { limit, offset } = query

  const reqData = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/kurbanlik',
    data: {
      limit,
      offset,
    },
  })
  const { data, total } = await reqData.data

  return {
    props: {
      data, // Hayvan Data (All Rows)
      total,
      query,
    },
  }
}
```

My table rows are based on this data. When I `onRowClick` any of the table rows, the page is redirected with `router.push` id query params. For ex. `localhost:3000/?id:102112`.
When I click on each row, the modal component specific to that row opens. And change id query params.

But I have a problem. When I click on each row, all the table data I got from the `getServerSideProps` is called again. I only need to do this when the first page is rendered.I don't need it to recreate the table data over and over.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shallow: true` in the `router.push` call to prevent `getServerSideProps` from running again.

From the [Shallow Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing) documentation:

> Shallow routing allows you to change the URL without running data
> fetching methods again, that includes `getServerSideProps`,
> `getStaticProps`, and `getInitialProps`.

```
router.push('/?id=102112', undefined, { shallow: true })
```